# Cómo cambiar el color de letra que se muestra en un td de mat table en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo la siguiente tabla que muestra una lista que regresa un servicio,
lo que quiero hacer es que el color de letra que se pinta en la columna CLAVE se pinte de diferente color dependiendo el valor, si la clave es igual a Error, se pinte el texto en color rojo, si la clave es Proceso se pinte el texto en color verde

```
           <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID  </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="cve">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CLAVE </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cve}} </td>
                </ng-container>


                <ng-container matColumnDef="severidad">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> SEVERIDAD </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.severidad}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
                    </tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
            </table>
```

component.ts

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'cve', 'severidad'];
            bit: Bitacora[] = [];

            constructor(private service: BitacoraService) { }

            ngOnInit(): void {
                this.obtenerLista();
            }

            dataSource: any;
            private obtenerLista() {
                this.service.obtenerLista().subscribe(response => {
                if (response.data.length == 0) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
                        })
                } else {
                    this.bit = response.data;
                    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.bit);
                }

            });
            }
```

Comment: con el inspector de F12 puedes ver las clases que se le aplican con material al elemento HTML, con que mires que clases es la que aplica el estilo, creo que es .mat-cell, como se indica en esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529743/change-angular-material-table-font-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando `ngStyle` es posible realizar dichos cambios, agrego código:

**HTML**

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngStyle]="{'color': cambiarColor(row.clave)}">
  {{row.clave}}
</td>
```

**Component**
Aquí tienes de varias formas, puedes tener varios `if-else` anidados o usar un `switch`, utilizando `switch` tienes la ventaja de que es más legible.

```
  cambiarColor(clave: string): string {
    switch (clave) {
      case 'En Proceso':
        return 'green';
      case 'Error':
        return 'red';
      case 'Finalizado':
        return 'blue';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
```

Comment: gracias,  se debe de agregar algo al css? algo como .color{ color: red;}  ??? o desde el component que dice return green, ya lo hace ?

Comment: Pues así me funciono

Comment: lo quise replicar cuando la clave esta dentro de un mat select, pero asi no  lo hace, de la otra forma si funciona bien, gracias

Comment: En `mat-select` es diferente.