# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un texto que se muestra en un mat table dentro de un mat select?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

Tengo la siguiente tabla que se llena al consultar un servicio, el campo ESTADO es un mat select, lo que quiero hacer es que dependiendo el valor del select que ya trae por default se muestre en un color diferente en la tabla, por ejemplo, si el estado es igual a INP que se pinte de color naranja, si el estado es igual a ERR que se pinte de color rojo.

al cargar mi pagina los campos se muestran deshabilitados, hasta que das click en el boton se habilitan para poder editarlos, pero quiero que al entrar a la pagina se muestre el color del estado, es posible? aunque la config al iniciar este deshabilitado? o que al dar click y se habiliten los campos se vea reflejado el color del estado seleccionado, se puede solo la letra? o también que el borde del select cambie de color

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollme">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idControl }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ESTADO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar">

              <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado">
                {{ estatus.descripcion }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>COMENTARIO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [value]="element.comentario" (keyup)="changeValue($event.target, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>HORA</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [value]="element.horaInicio" (keyup)="changeValueHora($event.target, element)"
              [disabled]="!element.editar" type="time" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>FECHAREGISTRO</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="element.fechaRegistro">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="element.fechaRegistro"
              (dateChange)="onDateChange($event.value, element)" [disabled]="!element.editar" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="botonSave">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>GUARDAR</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
          <button mat-button (click)="guardar(element)">Guardar</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

component

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from './Control';
import { ControlService } from './control.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-angular-material';
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'idControl',
    'cveEstado',
    'comentario',
    'horaInicio',
    'fechaRegistro',
    'botonSave',
  ];
  estadoModel: Estado[] = [];
  control: Control[] = [];
  controlModel: Control = new Control();
  estadoSeleccionado: any;
  idSeleccionado: string = '';
  comentIngresado: string = '';
  horaIngresada: string ='';
  fechaIngresada: any;
  dataModel: any[] = [];
  horaInvalida = true;
  
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    private controlService: ControlService,
    private dataAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>
  ) {
    this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerLista();
    this.obtenerListaEstados();
    
  }

  //obtiene la lista del servicio
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;
      console.log("PRUEBA " ,response.data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista de estados para el select
  private obtenerListaEstados() {
    this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log("PRUEBA  estados" ,response.data);
      this.estadoModel = response.data;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la cve del estado que se selecciona y su id
  cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
    this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;

    console.log(' ID SELECC ' + this.idSeleccionado);
    console.log(' ESTADO SELECC ' + this.estadoSeleccionado);
  }

  //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input coment  y el id
  changeValue(e: any, row: any) {
    this.comentIngresado = e.value;
    console.log(' INPUT COMENT  ' + this.comentIngresado);
  }

 //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input hora, y el id
 changeValueHora(e: any, row: any) {
  this.horaIngresada = e.value;
  console.log(' INPUT HORA   ' +this.horaIngresada);
  this.validarHora();
}

validarHora() {
  console.log(' ENTRA A VALIDAR HORA');
  const regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$");
  this.horaInvalida = !regex.test(this.horaIngresada);
  console.log('HORA '  + this.horaInvalida);
}


  //OBTIENE EL VALOR DE LA FECHA SELECCIONADA
  onDateChange(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.fechaIngresada = valor;
    console.log('FECHA SELECC  ' + this.fechaIngresada);
  }

  //funcion para darle formato a la fecha internamente
  formatDateToString(date: Date): string {
    if (date) {
      const format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
      const locale = 'en-US';
      return formatDate(date, format, locale);
    }
    return '';
  }

  guardar(element: any) {
    if (element.editar) {
      console.log(`Desactivado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = false;

      if (this.comentIngresado == '') {
        alert('No se han modificado campos');
      } else {
        console.log(' ENTRA ELSE  ');
        this.controlModel.cveEstado = this.estadoSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.comentario = this.comentIngresado;
        this.controlModel.idControl = this.idSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.fechaRegistro = this.formatDateToString(
          this.fechaIngresada
        );

        console.log('prueba fecha final  ' + this.controlModel.fechaRegistro);
        this.controlService
          .updateCampo(this.controlModel)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.controlModel = data;
            this.comentIngresado = '';
            this.estadoSeleccionado = '';
            this.fechaIngresada = '';

            alert('Agregado correctamente');
          });
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Activado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar el color de los elementos de la lista solamente agrega `[ngStyle]="{'color': cambiarColor(estado)}">` (reutilizando la función de la [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593495/325721)) dentro del `mat-option`.

Pero para mostrar el color del valor seleccionado directamente en la tabla está más complicado, las componentes de Angular Material están en otro 'nivel' entonces no es tan fácil aplicar CSS sobre ellos. Tendrías que experimentar con `ng::deep` o agregando `!important` a cada estilo CSS, tal vez manipular el DOM directamente de resultado pero no es una buena práctica hacerlo en Angular.

Comment: para hacerlo directamente en la tabla, el [ngStyle] tendria que estar en td mat-cell ?

Comment: No sabría decirte, intenté varias cosas y ninguna dio resultado. Lo único que medio funcionó fue agregar `[ngStyle]` pero usando `’background-color’` en lugar de `color` aunque no recuerdo si fue en el `mat-cell` o `mat-select` pero eso solo cambia el fondo, se ve como si estuviera subrayado con marca textos y no es muy legible.

Comment: es correcto, tambien tuve que ponerle la propiedad ’background-color’ y le quite al mat select la etiqueta <mat-field> por que apareceia como subrayado y lo que hace es poner de color la celda completa , gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si que se puede. Puedes usar la propiedad de angular ngClass que permite cambiar la clase del css a traves de una variable declarada en el component.
Podrias hacer lo siguiente `<mat-option [ngClass]="variable"></mat-option>`
variable seria una variable declarada en el componente.

Tambien puedes usar en el mismo ngClass condiciones, me explico.
`<mat-option [ngClass]="variable=='INPROGRESS'?classCSSX:classCSSY"></mat-option>`. Con esto consigues poner la clase de css que desees dependiendo del valor que tenga la variable.
Otro ejemplo seria definir una funcion y ejecutarla en el ngClass dando la clase de css que pondra el color o lo que quieras. `<mat-option [ngClass]="getCss(estatus.cveEstado)"></mat-option>`

Usando esto que te he explicado puedes jugar mucho con el css en tiempo de ejecucion. No te olvides que si usas esto tienes de tener en el archivo css la clase que usará ngClass.

O sea puedes usar ngClass en cualquien componente html, de angular o que crees tu, siempre poniendolo asi [ngClass]="".

Espero que esto te sirva para lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: gracias por la explicación